# sync.WaitGroup not behaving as I expect, what am I missing here?

Tags: go, goroutine

Given the following:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    n := 100

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(n)

    x := 0
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            x++
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(n, x)
}
```

I would expect `x` to always reach `100` by the time it prints at the end, but it sometimes prints as low as `95`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a race on `x`.  One fix is to protect `x` with a mutex:

```
var mu sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(n)

x := 0
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        mu.Lock()
        x++
        mu.Unlock()
    }()
}

wg.Wait()
fmt.Println(n, x)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/H5gaUNK2AM)

I suggest running the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) whenever one finds something puzzling in a Go program with more than one goroutine.

Answer (score 1):

use sync.atomic method to access x atomically.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
    n := 100

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(n)

    var x int32
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            atomic.AddInt32(&x, 1)
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(n, x)
}
```